# How to split single line csv file into multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

Could you please help me to figure out how to split a large single line csv file into rows with Python?

**Sample File:**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col82022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.02022-07-23 03:00:05,15.706,3765.808,274,30575,20486.0,151905.0,150725.02022-07-23 03:00:10,71.937,4507.922,845,39332,11654.0,31340.0,30925.02022-07-23 03:00:15,82.942,4246.146,937,36611,9177.0,3840.0,3974.02022-07-23 03:00:20,29.969,4122.618,408,33957,7657.0,3685.0,3733.02022-07-23 03:00:25,12.656,3630.578,190,29440,3671.0,2656.0,2663.02022-07-23 03:00:30,8.692,3240.102,108,26290,2576.0,2358.0,2359.02022-07-23
```

**Note:**
*If I open the file in Excel, the column names are displayed once. In a text editor, they show twice as above.*

**Required output**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8       
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
```

Thank you!

[Screenshot of actual file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJZRO.png)

Comment: If it's a single line then it's not (strictly speaking) a CSV file. If the comma-separated values are of fixed width (as per your example) then you could do this with string splitting. But they're probably not so you'll need to define some rules that define the layout. As a starting point you'd need to know the column header names then go from there

Comment: @Vlad I know the column names. Those are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Each group of values starts with a date / time sequence. Define a regular expression to match those. Identify the offsets of where those patterns occur then you can slice the string as follows:

```
s = 'Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col82022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.02022-07-23 03:00:05,15.706,3765.808,274,30575,20486.0,151905.0,150725.02022-07-23 03:00:10,71.937,4507.922,845,39332,11654.0,31340.0,30925.02022-07-23 03:00:15,82.942,4246.146,937,36611,9177.0,3840.0,3974.02022-07-23 03:00:20,29.969,4122.618,408,33957,7657.0,3685.0,3733.02022-07-23 03:00:25,12.656,3630.578,190,29440,3671.0,2656.0,2663.02022-07-23 03:00:30,8.692,3240.102,108,26290,2576.0,2358.0,2359.0'

m = re.finditer('([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})', s)
offsets = [0] + [m_.start(0) for m_ in m] + [len(s)]

for o in range(len(offsets)-1):
    print(s[offsets[o]:offsets[o+1]])
```

**Output:**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8
2022-07-23 03:00:00,101.346,4378.85,1106,37949,8737.0,11490.0,11412.0
2022-07-23 03:00:05,15.706,3765.808,274,30575,20486.0,151905.0,150725.0
2022-07-23 03:00:10,71.937,4507.922,845,39332,11654.0,31340.0,30925.0
2022-07-23 03:00:15,82.942,4246.146,937,36611,9177.0,3840.0,3974.0
2022-07-23 03:00:20,29.969,4122.618,408,33957,7657.0,3685.0,3733.0
2022-07-23 03:00:25,12.656,3630.578,190,29440,3671.0,2656.0,2663.0
2022-07-23 03:00:30,8.692,3240.102,108,26290,2576.0,2358.0,2359.0
```

**Note:**

Repeated column headers removed from source string for the purpose of this example. I have no idea why the input repeats the column headers. That must be an error on the part of whoever generates it

Answer (score 0):

For those interested or searching for a situation like this, below is how I solved the issue. Maybe not the cleanest or most elegant, but it did the trick for me.

```
with open(file_name, "r", newline="") as file:
    for line in file:
        split1 = line.split(")D")
        split2 = split1[1].split(")2")
        split3 = split2[1].split(".02022-")

        for i in split3:
            f = open("data.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
w.writerows([x.split(",") for x in split3])
f.close()
```